# Capacitor in 12VDC motor circuit

Tags: capacitor, dc-motor

I having an interesting issue with some cooling fans that came with a used pop up camper.  I'm proficient in electronics and this one just doesn't make any sense to me.  These fans are designed to be put in the camper like a portable box fan you would use in a house, but are much smaller.  They run on 12VDC and plug into outlets in the camper which are connected to a car battery.  When you turn a fan on it will run for about 30 seconds then the speed steadily declines and the fan stops.  If you switch the fan off, wait a few seconds and turn it back on it does the same thing.

I have taken these apart and they are really simple - power comes in from the plug, goes to a switch, then the motor and then (the weird part) to a capacitor in SERIES with the motor and then out to the plug.  I've never seen this.  I've seen lots of capacitors across little motors like these to clean up RF, but not in series like this.  To me this explains why the fan slowly shuts down - the capacitor charges and then becomes an open spot in the circuit.

To make this stranger, two of these fans exhibit this behavior and a third one does not.  They are all wired the same (though the capacitor on the one that works appears to be of a larger rating).  Maybe that capacitor has shorted?

Any thoughts?  Did someone in China make a whole bunch of mis-wired fans?  Am I ok to move the capacitor so that it is across the motor?  Or just get rid of it?  Or is there some motor thing that I'm unaware of?

Thanks, -D

Bruce and Dave - Thanks for the comments.  I'm not familiar with a PTC.  Here's a pic of the component -

[image: is this a capacitor?]

The markings on it appear to be FUMC CHINA on one side and on the other side
a symbol that looks like nested X's and 72 then x030 on the second line

The unit that works properly says
LP60 then 040 on the second line

I did do a search on 'LP60 040' and sure enough the first hit was a PTC.  So it looks like this is a PTC.  I did see where the stores selling these fans state that the motor is 'thermally protected', so then this must be how it is protected - this little guy senses too much current flow and then shuts down?

If that's the case all I have to is replace these and the fans will work again.

Thanks !!!

Comment: A capacitor that takes 30 seconds to charge up with the current a fan motor needs would be huge. Perhaps it's not a capacitor, but something else? Can you show us a picture?

Comment: Sounds more like a PTC thermistor (a.k.a. polyfuse) designed to limit fault currents. Its ratings may have drifted with age.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  Googled the numbers on one of the components and found it is a PTC.  Have ordered new ones and hopefully that gets this fixed.